# Can't connect to local (running) mongo using 'meteor mongo'

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm playing with meteor, Installed it on Ubuntu 14.10 & followed the [todos tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/try/3). The Meteor run log:

```
$ meteor run
[[[[[ ~/bckd/homedir/learn/meteor/mycoolapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Started your app.                          

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

When I try to connect to mongo via another terminal, I get:

```
$ meteor mongo
mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.
This command only works while Meteor is running your application locally. Start your
application first. (This error will also occur if you asked Meteor to use a different MongoDB
server with $MONGO_URL when you ran your application.)

If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed with `meteor deploy`,
specify your site's name with this command.
```

Trying to work around this problem I looked at the `mongo` command, and soon enough I figured I can connect using:

```
$ mongo localhost:3001
```

So great, that's working and it seems that I am able to use that for the time being.

But... why is the official way: `meteor mongo` not working in my setup, and can I do anything to fix it?

### Edit 5/6/2015

After creating another account on my ubuntu, logging in and creating a new app, I run it and managed to connect to the mongo instance as intended with the `meteor mongo` command (without sudo). I thought it could be a result of a difference in my environment variables so I compared the two (dumping both environments with the `env` command. There were some extra bash variables in my primary account so one by one I've unset them until I reached two identical environments (with the exceptions of home directory values, user names, auto-generated values for gnome session tokens and such). Despite those changes, the problem consists. Another wild guess of mine was that the `~/.meteor` folder has gone evil on me. So, I've removed it and reinstalled meteor. That didn't fix it either. Whatever the problem is, it's pretty stubborn.

Comment: where are you executing the `meteor mongo` command?

Comment: At the same directory, from a different terminal

Comment: I got exactly that problem, too. Could you solve yours?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo meteor mongo
```

it worked for me on a Vagrant box :)

Answer (score 4):

- You need to be the same user as the user who started Meteor.
- Also you need to connect from within the application directory.
- Can you connect to the database with the native MongoDB client?
- Try running `sudo meteor mongo` - maybe the Meteor/Node process is running as root.

Comment: Both conditions are met in my case, yet the problem consists

Comment: If you meant using: mongo localhost:3001, then yes - it works. I can add/remove items from the collection and the updates become visible within the clients

Comment: Hm weird, you could have a look into the Meteor binary and see why it is using a different connect String. As a last idea from me: In your app try printing out process.env.MONGO_URL. Can your app connect to the database?

Comment: Yes the app connects to the db, no problems there. I printed 
MONGO_URL and it seems to have the value: mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor
As for looking at the meteor binary, it seems that the binary is referred to using a few links which end at ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.3/mt-os.linux.x86_64/meteor . I could not find anything about mongo in it. This detail must be stored elsewhere

Comment: Hm that all seems to be alright... Which user are you running meteor as? Have you tried `sudo meteor mongo`? I can only think of some issues with permissions or connectivity.

Comment: Great! I run 'sudo meteor mongo' and it connected to the meteor mongo instance. Why is running under root privileges necessary in my case? Why would there be a permission problem? I've created the project with the same user I use to run the app and run the meteor mongo command!

Comment: Hard to say. Depends a lot on your OS configuration. Check `top` to see which user is running `node`.

Comment: I checked that, and as expected it's the same user. Strange.

Comment: Just noticed something: do you get the same results if you're just running `meteor` to start the server (without the `run` parameter`)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's your environment variable problem.

```
export MONGO_URL=''
meteor mongo
```

Comment: Tried that, Didn't work. Looks like MONGO_URL wasn't defined in my environment anyway

Comment: You don't need define MONGO_URL in env if you want to use meteor's minimongo.

Comment: Not sure I'm following. It wasn't defined in my case. Also, why is minimongo related? The problem I'm experiencing is server side...

Comment: I'm sorry, I've made a mistake, I mean the mongo provided by meteor on server side   -_-||

Answer (score 1):

Did you create the meteor app initially :
meteor create

I was having same issue on Ubuntu and found that i missed the create part as I copied the  code from windows machine.

Comment: To be on the safe side, I've just created a new app and run it. In a different terminal (same folder) I run 'meteor mongo' and bumped again into "Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server..."

Answer (score 0):

In my case(Windows 10),I had set MONGO_URL='remote url'.
In this case when you type 'meteor mongo' meteor will try to connect to the local mongodb server,but we are pointing to remote mogodb.

To point to local mongodb:

1) befor starting the app type 'set MONOGO_URL=' command in terminal.

2) now start the meteor app

3) now open a new terminal and try 'meteor mongo'

Comment: what should be the MONGO_URL value ??

Comment: @Ankita If you are refereing a remote MongoDB,means it's hosted on some other server give that url as MONGO_URL.eg:set MONGO_URL='http://example.com/mongodb' . If you are refereing the local mongodb you can just type set MONOGO_URL=(This is only required if you alreday pointed MONGO_URL to a remote URL)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with the same problem.

I had two terminals open: one running with **meteor** command, the other terminal I tried **meteor mongo** and received the very same message as stated in the question.

> mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.
>
> This command only works while Meteor is running your application locally. Start
>   your application first with 'meteor' and then run this command in a new
>   terminal. This error will also occur if you asked Meteor to use a different
>   MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when you ran your application.
>
> If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed with
>   'meteor deploy', specify your site's name as an argument to this command.

I tried the **sudo** command, which did not work as well.

> Here is what worked for me.

1. Goto running meteor server terminal and ctrl-c (shut down server).
2. In meteor server terminal type: **meteor mongo**.
   Note: In my case the command worked and the terminal entered into mongo.
3. Type **exit** to exit mongo.
4. Type **meteor** to spool back up meteor server.
5. Goto meteor mongo terminal and type: **meteor mongo**.
   Note: For me, Meteor was running in the other terminal and meteor mongo command did open meteor mongo for me without error.

Perhaps the something in Meteor needs to reboot which does not occur without shutting down meteor server first?

Answer (score 0):

check if there is a running mongo process, and kill it manually:

```
ps -aux | grep mongo
sudo kill [pid]
```

..then restart your meteor app.

--> I think this specific situation exists only when starting meteor on a custom port (not tested, but pretty obvious)