# When running meteor tests, how can I connect to the mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I have a new meteor application, and have a few tests that inserts data into a mongo collection, but no UI for that yet.

I have started a mocha test runner with `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`. If I try to start a mongo console with `meteor mongo` I get this error.

> mongo: Meteor isn't running a local MongoDB server.
>
> This command only works while Meteor is running your application
>   locally. Start your application first with 'meteor' and then run this
>   command in a new terminal. This error will also occur if you asked
>   Meteor to use a different MongoDB server with $MONGO_URL when you ran
>   your application.
>
> If you're trying to connect to the database of an app you deployed
>   with 'meteor deploy', specify your site's name as an argument to this
>   command.

How can I connect to the mongo to see which documents have been created by the tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local (running) mongo using 'meteor mongo'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29853700/cant-connect-to-local-running-mongo-using-meteor-mongo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When in 'test-mode', Meteor creates a dummy test-database to avoid overwriting data during testing.

This dB runs on port 3001 by default, but you cannot connect to it using `meteor mongo` ( you cannot specify the port )

If you have a real mongodb instance installed ( not the meteor built-in one), you can connect using:

`mongo meteor --port 3001`

Comment: I'm no longer using Meteor, but this seems like the answer I was looking for at the time I asked the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your environment variable problem.

```
export MONGO_URL=''
meteor mongo
```

You can also try if there is some permission issues :

```
sudo meteor mongo
```